# Angular environments default always to stage

Tags: angular

I have 3 environments in `environments/`: `environment.stage.ts`, `environment.prod.ts`, and `environment.ts`.

`environment.prod.ts`

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    stage: false,
    dev: false,
};
```

`environment.stage.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    stage: true,
    dev: false,
};
```

`environment.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    stage: false,
    dev: true,
};
```

Here is my `angular.json` build and serve options:

```
            "build": {
                "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                "options": {
                    "outputPath": "dist/artists",
                    "index": "src/index.html",
                    "main": "src/main.ts",
                    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                    "aot": false,
                    "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
                    "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
                    "scripts": []
                },
                "configurations": {
                    "dev": {},
                    "stage": {
                        "fileReplacements": [
                            {
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.stage.ts"
                            }
                        ],
                        "optimization": true,
                        "outputHashing": "all",
                        "sourceMap": false,
                        "extractCss": true,
                        "namedChunks": false,
                        "aot": true,
                        "extractLicenses": true,
                        "vendorChunk": false,
                        "buildOptimizer": true,
                        "budgets": [
                            {
                                "type": "initial",
                                "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                "maximumError": "5mb"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "production": {
                        "fileReplacements": [
                            {
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }
                        ],
                        "optimization": true,
                        "outputHashing": "all",
                        "sourceMap": false,
                        "extractCss": true,
                        "namedChunks": false,
                        "aot": true,
                        "extractLicenses": true,
                        "vendorChunk": false,
                        "buildOptimizer": true,
                        "budgets": [
                            {
                                "type": "initial",
                                "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                "maximumError": "5mb"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "serve": {
                "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                "options": {
                    "browserTarget": "artists:build"
                },
                "configurations": {
                    "dev": {
                        "browserTarget": "artists:build:dev"
                    },
                    "production": {
                        "browserTarget": "artists:build:production"
                    },
                    "stage": {
                        "browserTarget": "artists:build:stage"
                    }
                }
            },
```

However, whenever I run `ng serve -c prod` or just `ng serve` (which should default to dev) the flags `dev` and `production` are always false and `stage` is always true.

```
angular                           8.0.3
@angular-devkit/architect         0.800.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.800.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.800.6
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.800.6
@angular-devkit/core              8.0.6
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.0.6
@angular/cdk                      8.0.1
@angular/cli                      8.0.6
```

Comment: Could you post the version of Angular and Angular CLI you’re using? (This can be found by executing the `ng version` command) Could you post the code of the individual `environment.*.ts` files?

Comment: @Edric Updated with the version & other files

Comment: Could you try `ng serve -c=prod` with the equal sign?

Comment: You specified environment.ts twice and i do not see environment.stage.ts file

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets Sorry typo.